# Multi-platform programming language with GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface, serial-port, cross-platform

I want to create a multi-platform application with the focus on handling data from serial port, data processing/analysis and plotting. By now I wrote the application in Python (with a GUI generated by pyQTgraph) which works quiet well - but it is not possible to export my .py to .exe or .app (for Windows and Mac OS). I tried many tools like py2exe, PyInstaller, ...

Now I'm looking for a multi-platform programming language (C, C++, ..., but not Java) witch makes the transfer to other OS easy. Preferably it is possible to transfer the application frow Windows to Mac without big code-changes or redesigning the GUI. It is a lightweight application which should run without a previous installation.

- Do you have some hints which programming language and frontend (like QT) is the best for the job?
- Does your suggested language works well with serial-port-data?
- How does the workflow from writing the code to exporting the final .exe/.app looks like?

Best and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com). It builds separate, native apps for Windows, macOS and Linux from the same source project. It also has [serial support](http://developer.xojo.com/userguide/serial-devices).